# Limited File upload size with WebApi

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple WebApi using which I can upload file. Bellow the simple code for it

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> UploadSingleFile()
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;

        try
        {
            var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("D:\\");
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
            isSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

New I'm calling it in Form Submit from HTML `<form>` tag by using bellow code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://localhost:4952/api/UploadApi/UploadSingleFile" id="ajaxUploadForm" novalidate="novalidate">
<ol>
    <li>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="fileInput">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="button" id="ajaxUploadButton" class="btn">
    </li>
</ol>
</form>
```

I can upload any size of file using above code. But same API if I call using an Javascript ajax, the API action method throws error saying the file size exceeds the maximum size.

```
$('#ajaxUploadButton').click(function () {

    var data, xhr;

    data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $('#fileInput')[0].files[0]);

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:4952/api/UploadApi/UploadSingleFile', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (response) { };
    xhr.send(data);

})
```

So why is ajax not able to post large file? What actually happening in both code sets?

Answer (score 1):

This setting goes in your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The default is 4 MB.